# Implicit conversions applied where not required

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion, scalac

Scala apply implicit conversions where not required and make compilation fail with "Type mismatch" error.

**Example:**

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

case class Result(value: String)

implicit def intToResult(v: Int): Result = Result(v.toString)

val res: Result = Some(100).getOrElse(200/*wrong implicit intToResult call*/)
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(7, 46) type mismatch;
found   : Any
required: Result
val res: Result = Some(100).getOrElse(200)
```

The expression `Some(100).getOrElse(200)` should return a `Int` and scala should convert it into `Result` using `intToResult` via implicit convertion.

But Scala apply `intToResult` implicitly also on `getOrElse`'s  value breaking compile.

*IntelliJ doesn't show me any kind of error writing this expression, no syntax highlighting.*

**Tests:**

- Scala 2.11.8
- Scala 2.13.0

Comment: That is a good show case of why **implicit conversions** are _"evil"_ TM and should be avoided. It is always better to use **extension methods**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I agree with you! Unfortunately I’m working on legacy code...

Comment: Maybe you can refactor the **implicit conversion** for a **extension method** `asResult`. I do know that maybe that would be a titanic job... but, someone has to do it ;) Also, the compiler should just mark all places where the conversion is missing as a type check error. And finally, if it really a **titanic** job, maybe leave both, but stop using the conversion and use the extension method on new code, and slowly replace the old one. Good luck.